# ViewPager: add a new page by pulling right

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I try to create the following layout and functionality in my Android project:

The user can swipe through a bunch of pages until she reaches the rightmost page (fragment). By swiping left (pulling), a new page should be added and inserted on the right.

I know that I can use `notifyDatasetChanged()` to add a new page, but that doesn't provide the visual feedback => the user should get a feeling of pulling a new page from the right.

Are there any guidelines or tricks on how to implement that?

[image: ViewPager basic layout]

So far, I've implemented the basic ViewPager activity and a basic fragment by following the steps given here https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.

But this example requires the page count to be a constant number and does not provide any information on how to dynamically add a new page on swipe.